# A pyramid $ABCDS$ in which all edges have different lengths and $|AS|+|CS|=|BS|+|DS|$

Tags: geometry

I'm working on problems from the Polish *XI Olimpiada Matematyczna Gimnazjalistów* (question 7 from [this document](http://www.omg.edu.pl/uploads/attachments/1etap15.pdf). The deadline of 12 October 2015 has passed.

> Prove, that there exist a pyramid $ABCDS$ ($ABCD$ is a rectangle) in which each pair of edges have different lengths and $|AS|+|CS|=|BS|+|DS|$.

I can solve this exercise analytically but I don't know how to solve it in a synthetically.